# Can't get Twitter OAuth callback authentication to work in Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using MGTwitterEngine and OAuthConsumer frameworks.  And mostly following the instructions at [UsingOAuthConsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer).

In order to use OAuth and not have the user deal with the oob PIN based authentication, you need to enable a callback to the application.  To do this on a desktop (or iOS) application, you need to set up a custom URI scheme that goes to an event handler in the app.  I got this working, and tested it by using the custom URI in Safari.  My app does open and the correct method is invoked.  So far so good.

To do this for Twitter, you need to specify the callback URI in the settings for the application on Twitter's dev site.  Here the problem starts.  Twitter won't allow non-standard URIs.  So "myapp://oauth/" is not allowed.  It has to be an http or https URI.  All the websites I referenced say to put a placeholder here, and override in the request token request.  OK, so I put a dummy URL for my website here.  Now to implement the override.  Here's the code from one of the comments on how to so that:

```
OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:nil   
                                                                  realm:nil  
                                                      signatureProvider:nil]; 

[request setOAuthParameterName:@"oauth_callback" withValue:@"callbackurl:"];
```

When I add that second method call, the request to twitter now fails. NSURLErrorDomain error -1012 or something similar (I forgot to write down the number).

I tried a number of ways, but was never able to override the callback URL.  Does anyone have a sure-fire way of doing this?  For now, I've changed the app to use the OOB PIN authentication method, but I'd sure like to remove that unnecessary step for the user.

Thanks!

joe

Comment: Here's the specific error message:  failRequestToken: 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x5c43c30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x5c44ca0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}'

Comment: Anyone have any hints at all?  Even pointers to other forums where this is discussed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up on the OAuthConsumer framework and switched to the Google GTMOAuth framework. That works fine.

Comment: Do you have any hints what is wrong with the `oauth_callback` parameter? I can't get it to work if this parameter is something other than `oob`.